# Eclipse CDT Error Parser Problems

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm programming with Eclipse Indigo's CDT plug-in and I've been having some problems with the error parsers for some time.

The problem is that the parsers give me false errors when referencing a name defined in a file that is inside a project that does not build (i.e. it only contains header files). The projects referencing the headers still builds and runs normally.

I'm using the following error parsers (in order): 
CDT GNU C/C++ Error Parser 
CDT GNU Assembler Error Parser 
CDT GNU Linker Error Parser

Is there anyway to make the parsers recognize the references or am I forced to turn them off completelly?

Help appreciated!

Comment: For those who might have similar problems, try rebuilding the index. This is done by right-clicking your project and in submenu Index click rebuild.